# URL monitor 6.1 SSL handshake failed error in Dynatrace 6.1

Tags: dynatrace

URL monitor 6.1 was working fine till date but today I'm getting following exception:

SSL handshake failed, this may be caused by an incorrect certificate. Check 'Disable certificate validation' to override this. Exception message: peer not authenticated

Even I checked the Disable Certification validation check-box but issue doesn't get resolved.

I do have Dynatrace Client 6.1. Please suggest where should I check now.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you access the url with some other tool, e.g. browser, wget, curl, ...?

Comment: yeah I'm able to browse my site successfully with https protocol

Comment: It may be that the Java version in Dynatrace 6.1 does not support some newer SSL cipher. Was the SSL certificate replaced/renewed on your site recently?

Comment: Ok I will ask form network team about that but would be the further steps for me if they say Yes or No.